# What WordPress plugin should I use to make a 2 column layout for posts?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like a WordPress plugin that organizes my posts into 2 columns, and if possible adds infinite scrolling or is at least compatible with an infinite loader plugin.

I'm using Essential Grid right now but it makes my website load way slower. What plugin could I use to get this to work without painfully slowing down my website like Essential Grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WP Masonry Pro](http://www.masonrylayout.com/downloads/wp-masonry-layout-pro/) solves all of my problems, I recommend it to anyone looking for a good 2 column layout with infinite scroll. For some reason every setup I tried essential grid on it would load painfully slow.

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://www.masonrylayout.com/downloads/wp-masonry-layout-pro/)? It would be helpful to provide the link in your answer :)